# Return the price depending on the time from a link

Tags: python, url

So i got this link:

```
https://api.energidataservice.dk/dataset/Elspotprices?filter={"PriceArea":["DK1","DK2"]}&limit=50
```

I want to make the program output the current price depending on the time, but I dont know how to.

So far I have written this:

```
import requests

response = requests.get(
    'https://api.energidataservice.dk/dataset/Elspotprices?filter={"PriceArea":["DK1","DK2"]}&limit=50')
result = response.json()

for k, v in result.items():
    print(k, v)

records = result.get('records', [])
print(records)
print('records:')
for record in records:
    print('', record)

now = datetime.now()
current_time = now.strftime("%H:00:00")
print(current_time)
```

Now I need to make something look at the current time and then the list, or what you want to call it, and then output the SpotPriceDKK.

Comment: Do you want it for current hour (single output every time) or for all hours in a day?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `datetime` module for this, since [energidataservice](https://api.energidataservice.dk/dataset/Elspotprices?filter=%7B%22PriceArea%22:%5B%22DK1%22,%22DK2%22%5D%7D&limit=50) updates its data every hour. So you can get SpotPriceDKK of current hour using this `print(records[0]["SpotPriceDKK"])` , so your final code should be:

```
import requests

response = requests.get(
    'https://api.energidataservice.dk/dataset/Elspotprices?filter={"PriceArea":["DK1","DK2"]}&limit=50')
result = response.json()
records = result.get('records', [])

print(records[0]["SpotPriceDKK"])
```

Comment: I tried running this, but it returns the newest/data, not the price of the current time. –